# jQuery - SmartWizard. How can I override "Previous" button validation?

Tags: jquery, client-side-validation, smart-wizard

Basically, I need to validate data when the "Next" button is clicked, but if the user wants to go back I do not want to validate if they have introduced the required fields for the current step

```
    $('#wizard').smartWizard({ onLeaveStep: leaveAStepCallback,
            onFinish: onFinishCallback
        });

        function leaveAStepCallback(obj) {
            var step_num = obj.attr('rel'); // get the current step number
            return validateSteps(step_num); // return false to stay on step and true to continue navigation 
        }

        function onFinishCallback() {
            if (validateAllSteps()) {
                $('form').submit();
            }
        }

        // Your Step validation logic
        function validateSteps(stepnumber) {
            var isStepValid = true;

            if (stepnumber == 1) {
                var e = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownCustomers");
                var strCustomer = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                if (strCustomer == "-1") {
                    //alert("Please select a Customer.");
                    $('#wizard').smartWizard('showMessage', 'Please select a Customer.');
                    isStepValid = false;
                    return isStepValid;
                }
                else {
                    var d = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownTemplates");
                    var strTemplate = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
                    if (strTemplate == "-1") {
                        alert("Please select a Template.");
                        isStepValid = false;
                        return isStepValid;
                    }
                    else {
                        return isStepValid;
                    }
                    return isStepValid;
                }
            }

            if (stepnumber == 2) {

                if (document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_LabelMainDestData") != null) {
                    isStepValid = true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please introduce the Main Destination.");
                    isStepValid = false;
                }


                return isStepValid;

            }

            if (stepnumber == 3) {
                isStepValid = true;
                return isStepValid;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in showStep function just edit

```
if(stepIdx != curStepIdx)
```

to

```
if(stepIdx > curStepIdx)
```

it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Create a new var:

```
var OO_Back = false;
```

Then add "OO_Back = true" when clicked back button:

```
$($this.buttons.previous).click(function() {
    OO_Back = true;
    $this.goBackward();
    return false;
});
```

And last modify this condition to check y back button is clicked, you must set OO_Back = false after that:

```
 var curStep = $this.steps.eq($this.curStepIdx);
    if(stepIdx != $this.curStepIdx){
        if($.isFunction($this.options.onLeaveStep) && OO_Back == false) {
            var context = { fromStep: $this.curStepIdx+1, toStep: stepIdx+1 };
            if (! $this.options.onLeaveStep.call($this,$(curStep), context)){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
 OO_Back = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

just create another jsp page with case on step_number property which you can get from request and inside that jsp include your jsp according your step_number and assign that newly created jsp in your contentURL

Example

```
//inside your wizard page.
contentURL:'wizardcontent.jsp',

//'wizardcontent.jsp' is as follow

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%
    int step_number = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("step_number")!=null?request.getParameter("step_number"):"1");
    String url = "";
    switch (step_number){
        case 1:%>
            <jsp:include page="ddd.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <%break;
        case 2:%>
            <jsp:include page="xyz.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <%break;
        case 3:%>
            <jsp:include page="abcd.jsp"></jsp:include>
                   <%break;
    }

%>
```

Comment: Hi man. I am not sure if this solution would work for me since I am using asp.net. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
       $('.buttonPrevious').click(function () {
            // set true validation if you need
            return false;
        });
```

You must set valid true on back button if you need.

Try this for cancelled leaveAStepCallback function.

```
       $('#yourwizard').unbind('leaveAStepCallback');
```

If it won't work check out [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#event.stopImmediatePropagation.28.29).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked perfectly that is being guided by the accepted answer above.

```
onLeaveStep: function(obj, context){
       if(context.toStep > context.fromStep){ ...}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me when I used it:**

```
 function leaveStep(oStep, context) {
   //don't validate if the user is going backwards    
    if (context.toStep < context.fromStep)
    {
        $('#wizard').smartWizard('hideMessage');
        return true;
    }
   // continue to validate steps...
```